# django deployment : ASGI app does not loading static files

Tags: jquery, django, heroku, deployment

[WhiteNoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/) introduces itself : whitenoise works with any-**WSGI** compatible app.
Then, what package should I use for **ASGI** app??

Let's suppose url `/chatting/` is rendered by `index.html`.

For the first time we access `/chatting/`. When I **click** html `li` tag, this code is executed.

```
// Room join/leave
$("li.room-link").click(function () {
    roomId = $(this).attr("data-room-id");
    if (inRoom(roomId)) {
        // Leave room
        $(this).removeClass("joined");
        webSocketBridge.send({
            "command": "leave",
            "room": roomId
        });
    } else {
        // Join room
        $(this).addClass("joined");
        webSocketBridge.send({
            "command": "join",
            "room": roomId
        });
    }
});
```

[image: before]

[image: after]

**joined** class added successfully!!

However, after that(click event) Nothing is happen.
when I see log, it seems that websocket connection is still working.

[image]

Currently In my project, **ASGI** app failed to load jQuery static file.
What should I do for ASGI app to load jquery static file.

> I deployed my django project on Heroku. So I'd like to fix it in production environment.(in development environment it is working fine.)

below is my heroku Procfile setting.

```
web: gunicorn multichat.wsgi --log-file -
web2: daphne multichat.asgi:channel_layer --port $PORT --bind 0.0.0.0 -v2
worker: python manage.py runworker -v2
```

and it is index.html full code.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}MultiChat Example{% endblock %}
{% block header_text %}MultiChat Example{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    <ul class="rooms">
        {% for room in rooms %}
            <li class="room-link" data-room-id="{{ room.id }}">{{ room }}</li>
        {% empty %}
            <p class="empty">No chat rooms defined. Maybe make some in the <a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">admin</a>?</p>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

    <div id="chats">
    </div>

{% endblock %}


{% block extra_body %}
    <script>
        $(function () {
            // Correctly decide between ws:// and wss://
            var ws_path = "/chat/stream/";
            console.log("Connecting to " + ws_path);
            var webSocketBridge = new channels.WebSocketBridge();
            webSocketBridge.connect(ws_path);
            // Handle incoming messages
            webSocketBridge.listen(function(data) {
                // Decode the JSON
                console.log("Got websocket message", data);
                // Handle errors
                if (data.error) {
                    alert(data.error);
                    return;
                }
                // Handle joining
                if (data.join) {
                    console.log("Joining room " + data.join);
                    var roomdiv = $(
                            "<div class='room' id='room-" + data.join + "'>" +
                            "<h2>" + data.title + "</h2>" +
                            "<div class='messages'></div>" +
                            "<form><input><button>Send</button></form>" +
                            "</div>"
                    );
                    // Hook up send button to send a message
                    roomdiv.find("form").on("submit", function () {
                        webSocketBridge.send({
                            "command": "send",
                            "room": data.join,
                            "message": roomdiv.find("input").val()
                        });
                        roomdiv.find("input").val("");
                        return false;
                    });
                    $("#chats").append(roomdiv);
                    // Handle leaving
                } else if (data.leave) {
                    console.log("Leaving room " + data.leave);
                    $("#room-" + data.leave).remove();
                    // Handle getting a message
                } else if (data.message || data.msg_type != 0) {
                    var msgdiv = $("#room-" + data.room + " .messages");
                    var ok_msg = "";
                    // msg types are defined in chat/settings.py
                    // Only for demo purposes is hardcoded, in production scenarios, consider call a service.
                    switch (data.msg_type) {
                        case 0:
                            // Message
                            ok_msg = "<div class='message'>" +
                                    "<span class='username'>" + data.username + "</span>" +
                                    "<span class='body'>" + data.message + "</span>" +
                                    "</div>";
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            // Warning / Advice messages
                            ok_msg = "<div class='contextual-message text-warning'>" + data.message +
                                    "</div>";
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            // Alert / Danger messages
                            ok_msg = "<div class='contextual-message text-danger'>" + data.message +
                                    "</div>";
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            // "Muted" messages
                            ok_msg = "<div class='contextual-message text-muted'>" + data.message +
                                    "</div>";
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            // User joined room
                            ok_msg = "<div class='contextual-message text-muted'>" + data.username +
                                    " joined the room!" +
                                    "</div>";
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            // User left room
                            ok_msg = "<div class='contextual-message text-muted'>" + data.username +
                                    " left the room!" +
                                    "</div>";
                            break;
                        default:
                            console.log("Unsupported message type!");
                            return;
                    }
                    msgdiv.append(ok_msg);
                    msgdiv.scrollTop(msgdiv.prop("scrollHeight"));
                } else {
                    console.log("Cannot handle message!");
                }
            });
            // Says if we joined a room or not by if there's a div for it
            inRoom = function (roomId) {
                return $("#room-" + roomId).length > 0;
            };
            // Room join/leave
            $("li.room-link").click(function () {
                roomId = $(this).attr("data-room-id");
                if (inRoom(roomId)) {
                    // Leave room
                    $(this).removeClass("joined");
                    webSocketBridge.send({
                        "command": "leave",
                        "room": roomId
                    });
                } else {
                    // Join room
                    $(this).addClass("joined");
                    webSocketBridge.send({
                        "command": "join",
                        "room": roomId
                    });
                }
            });
            // Helpful debugging
            webSocketBridge.socket.onopen = function () {
                console.log("Connected to chat socket");
            };
            webSocketBridge.socket.onclose = function () {
                console.log("Disconnected from chat socket");
            }
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

I referenced this [project](https://github.com/andrewgodwin/channels-examples/blob/master/multichat/)
I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

WhiteNoise will work with Channels, just add it to the MIDDLEWARE list in `settings.py`:
http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html#enable-whitenoise

Comment: I already have tried that way. I already set up `MIDDLE_WARE_CLASSES, STATICFILES_STORAGE` in setting.py. 
But that does not resolve this issue.

Comment: If the problem is that your static files are not loading then we don't need to see your HTML and JS, but we do need to see your `settings.py`

Comment: If so, your comment is right.
however when I accessed root url, I saw the rendered html page. it means that my bootstrap3 min file, js min file, css file are loaded well.