# static files for django admin can't be found while running asgi server

Tags: django, static, asgi

Here is my settings.py

```
# ...other settings

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# ...other settings
```

Then I run

```
python manage.py collectstatic

uvicorn Django_Channels.asgi:application --port 8000 --workers 4 --log-level debug --reload
```

this collects static (after that I do have **static** folder at the root folder), starts the asgi server, but when I go to the admin page it looks like without any CSS or JS files. Just a bunch of unorganised text.

Here are the logs from terminal:

```
Here what logs look likeINFO:     
127.0.0.1:51770 - "GET /static/admin/css/dashboard.css HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found
Not Found: /static/admin/css/responsive.css
INFO:     127.0.0.1:51770 - "GET /static/admin/css/responsive.css HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found
Not Found: /static/admin/js/theme.js
INFO:     127.0.0.1:51769 - "GET /static/admin/js/theme.js HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found
Not Found: /static/admin/js/nav_sidebar.js
INFO:     127.0.0.1:51770 - "GET /static/admin/js/nav_sidebar.js HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found
```

I am always having a bad time with staticfiles, could please somebody tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is a lot of related questions at the same topic you could read.

Comment: whitenoise works with asgi, look at this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46133931/django-deployment-asgi-app-does-not-loading-static-files

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in related questions and in the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/), static files can be served when you set `DEBUG=True` (for your development purposes only). Otherwise you have to include the static files path into your web server configuration.

> **Serving the files**
>
> In addition to these configuration steps, you’ll also need to actually serve the static files.
>
> During development, if you use django.contrib.staticfiles, this will be done automatically by runserver when DEBUG is set to True (see django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve()).
>
> This method is grossly inefficient and probably insecure, so it is unsuitable for production.
>
> See How to deploy static files for proper strategies to serve static files in production environments.